# With E4X, can I turn off indentation?

Tags: javascript, xml, indentation, rhino, e4x

If I've got something like:

```
var x = <div><span>hello</span><span>world</span></div>
```

and add it to some other expression, it gets rendered as:

```
<div>
  <span>hello</span>
  <span>world</span>
</div>
```

But in HTML, the whitespace between `</span>` and `<span>` is significant.

Is there a way to turn off the auto-indentation that E4X does?

I'm using Rhino JS, but obviously a standard mechanism would be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just set `XML.prettyIndent = 0`. If you want to turn off pretty printing entirely, just set `XML.prettyPrinting = false`. You can read about more switches on the [MDC E4X tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/E4X_Tutorial/The_global_XML_object).

Comment: I'd grant the +200 here, but when I click that, SO gives me the JS alert box, and when I click OK it shows the orange warning div that says simply "(click on this box to dismiss)".

Comment: Mods can't do jack about bounties and awarding points, but I have used my moderator wand to grant you three wishes, as long as they are doable within a reasonable time frame, at a good price point, and I don't have to actually grant them.

Comment: Eli: Right, it was deducted when I created the bounty (I had 223 before this).  Or does a bounty of 200 mean I lose 200 points, and then later also have the option of transferring 200 *more* points from me to someone?  Is that what the empty error-message-box was trying to tell me?

Comment: I don't know, it must've been some bug.